# cx_Oracle executemany vs executemanyprepared

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have this function in python

`def insert_multi(connection, stmt, data):
    """
    insert multiple records with executemany
    :param connection: cx_oracle connection
    :param stmt: prepared insert statement
    :param data: insert data
    :return:
    """
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.prepare(stmt)
    cur.executemany(None, data)
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()`

How does this approach differ from the cx_oracle method on a cursor object `executemanyprepared`? 
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html

How would I use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor method executemanyprepared() is only intended to be used when the data you intend to pass is *already* included in the bind variables bound to the cursor. Generally this only happens if you are fetching from one cursor and then binding that data directly to another cursor. In all other situations, calling cursor.executemany() passing the data is going to be the right solution.

Hope that answers your question!